# List products from parent category in Openerp

Tags: odoo, categories, product

I'm using OpenERP V7.

I have the following structure:

- Category 1

  - Subcategory A

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
  - Subcategory B

    - Product 3
    - Product 4
- Category 2

  - Subcategory C

    - Product 5
    - Product 6

I would like to list all the products under `Category 1`. But I can only list the products if I search for `Subcategory A` or `Subcategory B`. If I search for `Category 1` it shows an empty list.

I saw similar questions:

- https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-can-i-search-products-by-ancestor-category-62717
- https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/list-products-in-all-subcategories-10874

But I can't make it work with any of the solutions there. I think I'm missing some step. What would be the best way to solve it?

Edit: Also found this module: https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/product_category_full_search/ I can install it but after the installation It doesn't seem to work, if I look for `Category1` it's still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way, it's explained in the [second link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/list-products-in-all-subcategories-10874).

I was modifying the file product_view.xml. But as explained [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/why-my-xml-changes-have-no-effect-at-all-63722), the XML files are uploaded into the database for faster response, meaning that the changes done in the file itself in your computer won't have a direct effect on the server, unless you update the module.

There were two ways of solving my question:

1. You create a module (there are some tutorials around explaining that) and then you install it.

The code for the view would be:

```
<record id="view_product_search_child_categories" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.search.categories</field>
    <field name="model">product.product</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_search_form_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="categ_id" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="operator">child_of</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Or the other option:

2. You create a view directly from within OpenERP interface. In my case I did:

   - Enable the Technical features of my admin user.
   - Go to Settings>Technical>User Interface>Views>Create:

     - View name: `product.search.categories`
     - View type: (it will display `Tree` but after saving will change to `Search`)
     - Object: `product.product`
     - Child Field: empty
     - Inherited view: `product.search.form`
     - External ID: empty

In the architecture write:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <field name="categ_id" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="operator">child_of</attribute>
    </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Sales --> Products --> Products by Category menu and delete the filter in search bar. You'll have all product of the category tree.

Or you can create a filter like

```
<filter string="NAME" icon="terp-accessories-archiver" domain="[('categ_id','child_of',X]"/>
```

where X is the ID of your category. You can use a list of categories like 
    domain="[('categ_id','child_of',[X,Y])]"

Comment: I saw that answer on the 2nd link I shared. That doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Yaseen, but I don't see where I should put that piece of code.

Comment: You can use it in the group by part of the search filter for the list of products.

Comment: Thats great Eric, do share if there's a better method...:-)